# Cordova Ionic with CrossWalk plugin Resolution Issue

Tags: ionic-framework, crosswalk

Before I installed CrossWalk, my ionic app looks like this
[image]

But after I installed crosswalk plugin, my app looks like this.
[image]

Looks like everything is smaller in crosswalk.
Is there any config I can change to make screen content larger in CrossWalk?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding this line in index.html

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```